# assigning file data to array of arrays

Tags: arrays, file

I'm trying to read a text file having 7 lines into an array like this:

## include

void main( )

{
    FILE *fp;

```
char *buffer[7];    //buffer is an array of 7 pointers to char

int i;

if ((fp = fopen("filetext", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("There was an error opening file\n");
}

for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    if (fgets(buffer[i], sizeof(char), fp)) != NULL) {;
        printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
        i++
    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

}

** Some more questions
Why does this not work?
does fgets, fgetc, fscanf and fread automatically go to the next line by itself ?
do they also automatically increment to the next array element?

I've been trying this for 3 days now, and i'm so frustrated.

Comment: Tag what language you are using/compiling, and make sure your code is formatted (not all code is in a code block).

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't helpful. Explain what the problem is.

Comment: i'm coding in c, compiling with gcc. The problem is, i'm trying to read a file which contains 7 lines of data. I want to be able to to read each line into each array element initialized as (char *buffer[7]) -> Which i use to interpret as buffer is an array of 7 pointers  to char ... obviously i'm wrong. My understanding was when initialized like this, the compiler allocates an array in which each of its elements points to a location in memory that holds the beginning of a string which will be put there when each line is read from the file.

Comment: My other questions also are :  does fgets, fgetc, fscanf and fread automatically go to the next line by itself ? do they also automatically increment to the next array element?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your buffers to store the input are not allocated.

You need to prepare some room to store the strings.

Change your declaration

```
char *buffer[7];
```

That allocates 7 pointers, that don't point anywhere significant to

```
char buffer[7][1024];
```

where 1024 is longer than the longest line you might encounter, this allocates 7k bytes to store the data.

This way buffer[i] will be an address where 1024 bytes may be written.

Reuse this constant in `fgets` as second parameter.

See this documentation for details :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Read Kernighan & Ritchie to understand C strings http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf
, or just copy from examples in the doc like the one I pointed to. And try reading the manual of your function 'fgets' the answers to the rest of your questions are there in the first paragraph.

Comment: when you define it like this ( char buffer[7][1024] ) isn't this a 2 dimensional array , if it is, then what's the logic behind it ? and i'm coding in c

Comment: My other questions also are :  does fgets, fgetc, fscanf and fread automatically go to the next line by itself ? do they also automatically increment to the next array element?

Comment: Please I still have a question. U said the way I initialized buffer, that it isn't allocated, but in we write this ( char buffer[7]; ) and its valid... So why is (char *buffer[7] ) invalid ???

Comment: #include <stdio.h>


int main( )
{

 FILE *fp;
 char *buffer[7][11];    //buffer is an array of 7 pointers to char
 int i, j;

 if ((fp = fopen("Jeffrey", "r")) == NULL) {
      printf("There was an error opening file\n");
 }

 for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
  for (j=0; (buffer[i][j] != '\0'); j++) {
   buffer[i][j] = fgets(buffer[i][j], 11, fp);
   printf("%s\n", buffer[i][j]);
  }
 }

 fclose(fp);
   

}

this prints just the first line and segfauls, please what am i still doing wrong ?